# How remove entry in join table many-to-many relation (ASP. NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

i'm trying to remove the entry in the relation table "SongPlaylist" but can't select the entry by using where, is there any solution to delete this relation ?

There is my 3 models:

```
public int SongId { get; set; }
public IList<SongPlaylist> SongPlaylist { get; set; }
```

```
public int PlaylistId { get; set; }
public IList<SongPlaylist> SongPlaylist { get; set; }
```

```
public int SongId { get; set; }
public Song Song { get; set; }
public int PlaylistId { get; set; }
public Playlist Playlist { get; set; }
```

And this is how i'm trying to delete the relation:

```
var RelationToDelete = _context.SongPlaylist.Where(x => x.PlaylistId == playlistId && x.SongId == songId).First();
```

I dont want to delete the playlist object and the song object, only the relation between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var removingRows= _context.Set<SongPlaylist>().Where(x => x.PlaylistId == playlistId && x.SongId == songId).ToArray();

if(removingRows != null)
{
_context.Set<SongPlaylist>().RemoveRange(removingRows);
_context.SaveChanges();
}
```

if you sure that you have to remove  only one row:

```
var removingRow=_context.Set<SongPlaylist>().Where(x => x.PlaylistId == playlistId && x.SongId == songId).FirstOrDefault();

if(removingRow != null)
{
_context.Set<SongPlaylist>().Remove(removingRow);
_context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried qith include the related entity?

somehting like:

```
var RelationToDelete = _context.SongPlaylist.include(yy=>yy.Playlist).Where(x => x.PlaylistId == playlistId && x.SongId == songId).First();
```

Comment: Not working, i still have the error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: are you sure about id are you passing?